# Sorting sub list of integer from another list without affecting the main list

Tags: java

So for the below code

```java
public static int activityNotifications(List<Integer> expenditure, int d) {
    int n = expenditure.size();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i < (n-d-1); i++) {
        List<Integer> subList = expenditure.subList(i, (d + i + 1));
        Collections.sort(subList);
        int median = median(subList, d);
        System.out.println("median : " + median + " i: " + i);
        System.out.println("compare to : " + expenditure.get(i + d));
        System.out.println("\n");

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(" " + expenditure.get(j));
        }
        if (expenditure.get(i + d) >= median * 2) {
            count ++;
            System.out.println("count: " + count);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

while sorting the subList, that part of the main expenditure list is also sorted.

I want to keep the main list unsorted and the subList to be sorted.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Copy it:

```
List<Integer>  subList = new ArrayList<>(expenditure.subList(i,(d+i+1)));
// Now this is sorting a separate instance of the list, not a view.
Collections.sort(subList);
```

or, copy it and sort it at the same time:

```
List<Integer> subList =
    expenditure.subList(i,(d+i+1)).stream()
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```